# Google Sheets Question: Move a Third of My Column Data

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to re-sort a column in google sheets by grabbing the bottom third of the filled cells and putting them on top of the other cells. Is there a easy way to do this? I need it to autopopulate in the future so it has to use a function.

I've looked into the FILTER, OFFSET, SORT functions but haven't succeeded yet.

Comment: please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result.

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) .

Answer (score 0):

If you have the column of filled cells in A:A, the formula below when placed in any cell in any other column will give you a reordered list of the filled cells with the bottom 2/3rds of filled cells at the beginning of the list as requested. The source column of filled cells in A:A does not need to be contiguous (i.e. gaps will be ignored).

```
=arrayformula(let(
array,tocol(A:A,1),
order,sequence(counta(array)),
reorder,if(order>((2/3)*max(order)),order-max(order),order),
sort(array,reorder,1)))
```